# A box contains 5 blue and 4 red balls. (probability problem)

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-theory

A box contains 5 blue and 4 red balls. Two balls are drawn successively from the 
box  without  replacement,  and  it  is  noted  that  the  second  one  is  red.  What  is  the 
probability that the first is also red?
(My answer is: 4/9 * 1 .is it true?)

Comment: Nope. It's without replacement and you already picked one that is red, so the probability for the other one is $\frac{4-1}{9-1} = \frac{3}{8}$.

Answer (score 4):

So there are two things that can happen here.  On the second pick, you are picking a red ball for sure.  So we can have two different probabilities here.  Why?  Suppose the first ball you picked was blue.  Then that blue / red combination probability would be
$$\frac{5\cdot{4}}{9\cdot{8}}$$
Now suppose the first ball you picked was red.  Then that red / red combination probability would be
$$\frac{4\cdot{3}}{9\cdot{8}}$$
So let A be the event that you pick a red ball first and let B be the event that you pick a red ball second.  Then we have the conditional probability:
$$P(A|B)=\frac{P(A\cap{B})}{P(B)}=\frac{\frac{4\cdot{3}}{9\cdot{8}}}{\frac{5\cdot{4}+4\cdot{3}}{9\cdot{8}}}=\frac{12}{32}=\frac{3}{8}$$